# Calculate area under a highcharts curve

Tags: highcharts

I am looking for ways to calculate the area under a highcharts curve (integral). I have been looking but so far I haven't found nothing. Is there any tool available for me to do this?

Comment: What you mean by calculate area under highcharts? Add extra serie, calculate points which are in area (for custom tooltip) ?